# How to build a LINQ to XML query with a conditional selection

Tags: c#, xml, linq, conditional-statements

The xml elements are variable depending on some conditional.  I need to initialize an instance with a different element, based on the value of some other element.

```
var result = (from name in names
   select new MyName
   {
      name.First  = name.Type = Fracais ? name.PreNom : name.First,
      name.Last 
   }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show an XML sample that shows the problem you have?

Comment: Can you describe in detail what exactly do you want? What's wrong with the code you posted? (Except the fact that it should be `name.Type == Fracais`.)

Comment: If you can post the other related classes and constants/enums we can provide a more accurate answer as it looks like you just have a few typoes :)

Comment: how is this Linq to XML though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is almost right. I had to guess the enums and members as you don't provide the other classes:

```
   var result = from name in names
                 select new Person()
                   {
                      First = name.Type == PersonType.Fracais ? name.PreNom : name.First,
                      Last = name.Last
                   };
```

You can have pretty much any expression, including function calls, in a linq query, so testing values and mutating them on the fly is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: +1: A small explanation of the problem would elevate this answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I was told this did not work and didn't have enough skepticism, so I never tried.  1 kiloPardon please?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? As a pointless alternative.

```
var result = names.where(name => name.Type == Francais).Select(name =>
                                           name.PreNom, name.Last).Union()
    names.where(name => name.Type != Francais).Select(name.First, name.Last);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the original (except for naming of elements and typoes... and the == as far as I can see:)). Why make it harder to read with a Union?

Comment: That's a big workaround. Changing `=` to `==` would work just as well :)